# Lisp return String of Symbol name

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols

Basically I'm looking for a function that does the opposite of the following.

```
(intern "CAR")
```

This question is related. [In Common Lisp, is there a function that returns a symbol from a given string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038155/in-common-lisp-is-there-a-function-that-returns-a-symbol-from-a-given-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The operator you are looking for is `string` (see the [manual](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_string.htm)):

```
(string (intern "CAR"))
```

returns "CAR".

Answer (score 8):

Either `string` or `symbol-name` would work to get the name of a symbol.

If you know specifically that you're passing n a symbol, `symbol-name` might allow both a compiler to generate better code as well as signal to a human reader that the argument is expected to be a symbol.